# How does "sizeof" work in this helper for determining array size?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, size

I've found [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/the1/archive/2004/05/07/128242.aspx) that brings up the following template and a macro for getting array size:

```
template<typename Type, size_t Size>
char ( &ArraySizeHelper(Type( &Array )[Size]) )[Size];
#define _countof(Array) sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(Array))
```

and I find the following part totally unclear. `sizeof` is applied to a function declaration. I'd expect the result to be "size of function pointer". Why does it obtain "size of return value" instead?

Comment: No, it is applied to the function return value.

Comment: Just want to note that in C++11, the `countof` function he tries halfway through can be made to yield a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
template<typename Type, size_t Size>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(Type(&Array)[Size]))[Size];
#define _countof(Array) sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(Array))
```

> `sizeof` is applied to a function declaration. I'd expect the result to be "size of function pointer". Why does it obtain "size of return value" instead?

It's not `sizeof ArraySizeHelper` (which would be illegal - can't take `sizeof` a function), nor `sizeof &ArraySizeHelper` - not even implicitly as implicit conversion from function to pointer-to-function is explicitly disallowed by the Standard, for C++0x see 5.3.3).  Rather, it's `sizeof ArraySizeHelper(Array)` which is equivalent to `sizeof` the value that the function call returns, i.e.  `sizeof char[Size]` hence `Size`.

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` is applied to the result of a function *call*, not a declaration. It therefore gives the size of the return value, which in this case is a reference to an array of chars.

The template causes the array in the return type to have the same number of elements as the argument array, which is fed to the function from the macro.

Finally, `sizeof` is then applied to a reference to this char array. `sizeof` on a reference is the same as `sizeof` on the type itself. Since `sizeof(char) == 1`, this gives the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 3):

`ArraySizeHelper` is a function template which returns a `char` array of size `Size`. The template takes two parameters, one is *type* (which is `Type`), and other is *value* (which is `Size`).

So when you pass an object of type, say, `A[100]` to the function. The compiler *deduces* both arguments of the template: `Type` becomes `A`, and `Size` becomes `100`.

So the instantiated function return type becomes `char[100]`. Since the argument of `sizeof` is never evaluated, so the function need not to have *definition*. `sizeof` only needs to know the *return type* of the function which is `char[100]`.  That becomes equivalent to `sizeof(char[100])` which returns 100 -  the size of the array.

Another interesting point to be noted is that `sizeof(char)` is not compiler-dependent, unlike other primitive types (other than the variants of *char*<sup>1</sup>). Its ALWAYS `1`. So `sizeof(char[100])` is guaranteed to be `100`.

<sup>1. Size of all variants of `char` is ONE, be it `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char` according to the Standard.</sup>

Comment: Why is it sizeof(char[100]) instead of "size of function pointer"?

Comment: @sharptooth: Because it's a function call. `sizeof` and `decltype` operate on the return type of function calls.

Comment: @sharptooth: Explained that by adding few more sentences.