# Why is "reference to array" defined in such confusing way in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, declaration

The following code is based on a snippet [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6106158/57428). I want a templated function that accepts a reference to an array of size that is deduced when the function is instantiated:

```
template<int size>
void myFunction( SomeType(&param)[size] )
{
    //use param and size here
}

//called like this:
SomeType array[SomeConstant];
myFunction( array ); //SomeConstant magically gets into the function as "size"
```

Now I'm confused with `SomeType(&param)[size]`. I'd expect the following to work:

```
template<int size>
void myFunction( (SomeType[size])& param ) {}
```

but it wouldn't compile.

Why do I need such weird syntax for "reference to array of fixed size"?

Comment: A better question is, why would you ever used fixed-size arrays? Have programmers really learned *nothing* from all the buffer-overflow hacks plaguing so much software? I personally blame stupid teachers who teach this stuff in the first place.

Comment: @Blindy: Do you believe using `vector` automatically guarantees against a buffer overrun?

Comment: Because the C declaration syntax was designed to punish mankind for its sins.

Comment: @sharptooth. Yes (I believe vector guarantees against overrun). Just use at() not opetator[]

Comment: @Blindy: You do notice that the size of the array is known to the function, yes?

Comment: @Blindly: How many colors would you have if you work with 32-bit colors system?

Comment: @Martin: Okay, but how do I pass my buffer to a library written in C then?

Comment: @Martin: That's not automatic, now is it?

Comment: @sharptooth, @Ben, yes, `vector` protects against overrun as long as you're using it right. @Dennis, yes, your point? @Nawaz, same question, your point? I am honestly horrified of looking at any of your code if you're defending fixed-size arrays.

Comment: @Blindy: The point is that a fixed size array with a known size is precicely as safe as a variable length array with a known size.  In fact, in this case it is *more* safe, because the compiler takes care of the size for you... if the size of the array changes, there is zero risk of `myFunction` getting called with the wrong size.

Comment: @Blindy: arrays "protect" against overrun as long as you're using them right. It's possible to overrun either an array or a vector, and doing so in both cases *by definition* is using it wrong. Vector makes certain things easier, but it would be wrong to assert either that *anything* done with an array is difficult, or that *anything* done with a vector is easy. @Martin: don't forget that to get that guarantee, also you must not use `vector::iterator::operator+` or `operator++`.

Comment: For an example of a use of fixed-size arrays that is not dangerous: string literals are fixed-size arrays. `std::string foo = "foo";` uses a fixed-size array. It is hardly horrifying. You're wrongly assuming the copying of data willy-nilly into buffers with ad-hoc bounds checking. That is one possible use of fixed-size arrays, and it's inadvisable to do it in a language where you can avoid it since "ad-hoc" checking frequently turns out to be "bug-ridden" checking...

Comment: @Steve, that's different, `"foo"` resides in read-only memory and you're using it through a `string` wrapped copy. And I'm pretty sure iterators do bounds checking.

Comment: @Blindy: it's different from what? From what you guessed (without any information) that sharptooth's real code does? Are you saying that if `myFunction` took a `const SomeType(&param)[size]` then there would be no problem? For all you know, `SomeType` might already be a const type, via a typedef. It's just an example for the sake of illustrating the syntax, it doesn't tell you anything else about the real code. Secondly, iterators are *not* guaranteed to do bound checking, sharptooth and Ben should pretty much pile on now and say that your code is rubbish if you think they are.

Comment: Oh, and my point is that I'm not just using `"foo"` through a string-wrapped copy. I'm using it *to create* the string. That's using it. And no buffers were overrun. It is conceivable to me that sharptooth has found some other uses of arrays, which also do not overrun any buffers.

Comment: @Steve, `const` is almost nothing in C, you can cast it away easily, whereas a string resides in read-only memory so even if you do overflow it, you still can't *write*. It is quite different, yes.

Comment: @Blindy: String literals are *not* guaranteed to reside in read-only memory. It is undefined behavior to attempt to modify them, in much the same way that it is UB to modify a `const` object having cast away `const` from some reference to it. On some implementations, that UB manifests as actually modifying the memory where the literal is stored.

Comment: @Steve, and just to finish this because it's getting *embarassing*, real STL implementations ***will do bounds checking on iterators in debug mode***. Fire up your MSVC and test it for yourself (it even throws an exception in release mode). Then try to disprove that string literals are not in read-only memory. It's not my code you should be worried about.

Comment: @Blindy: oh, right, you only ever program for one particular environment? This is different, this is a question about the C++ language in general. Sure, then for you, iterators check bounds, and for you, it's OK to write code that risks modifying a string literal, because it'll cleanly kill the process instead of doing something unexpected and dangerous. Others can't make those assumptions, and have to be more cautious in everything they do - that caution qualifies them to use arrays.

Comment: @Blindy: No, you must not cast away `const` in C or C++, unless you added it to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your second declaration becomes what value should be used as the identifier?  Should it be `param`, or should it be `SomeType`?  Because of the parenthesis, the first part of the declaration would be parsed first, but if that's the case, and `SomeType` was not the identifier, then at what point in the parsing does the identifier get named?

Using the [clockwise parsing pattern](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) of C/C++, where the identifier is the the inner-most unknown parsed element (i.e., something that isn't a known token or keyword ... see the link), syntax like

```
(SomeType[size])& param
```

would read "SomeType is an array of fixed 'size' that is a reference-type type for some object `param`" which of course doesn't make any sense since the array has not been declared with the type of object that it is an array of.  On the otherhand

```
SomeType(&param)[size]
```

using the same parsing rules would read "`param` is a reference to an array of fixed size that contains objects of type `SomeType`".  The latter is of course the declaration you want, and what makes sense to the C/C++ parser.

Answer (score 4):

It's based on the C declaration syntax. Of course, C doesn't have references, but it's meant to mimic the C syntax for pointers. Here's a pointer to an array (in C or C++):

```
int (*parray)[size];
```

The idea is that the declaration mimics the usage. It's meant to suggest that later on when you use `parray`, the expression

```
(*parray)[0]
```

(or whatever index) is of type int. Of course, the symmetry breaks down for reference types, since the `&` is used while declaring them but not referring to them.

Answer (score 3):

It's for consistency with C array declaration syntax.

With your proposed syntax, you'd also write:

```
int*[4] x;
```

instead of

```
int* x[4];
```

That's not a bad choice, but it's not what C uses, and C++ tries to be compatible.

Answer (score 1):

When declaring you should follow the rule:

> Start form the name, go right when you can, go left when you must.

this rule is completely described in this useful link, and `&` is handled as `*`, this is the link:

http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

In you delecration, you put `[]` before the name of the variable, which is illegal. The rule is that every `*` and `&` should come before the name, and every `[]` and `()` should come after the name.