# Pointers to int in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, error-handling

What is wrong in that: I just wanted to pointers to int and give that ints value of 0.

```
    int* p;int* q;

*p = 0; *q = 0;
cout<<"p = "<<*p<<" q = "<<*q<<endl;
```

This is annoying

WORKS:

```
int* p;
   *p = 0;

   cout<<*p<<endl;
```

CRASHES:

```
     int* p;
   int* q;
   *p = 0;
   *q = 0;

   cout<<*p<<endl;
```

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer#Cause_of_wild_pointers

Comment: Duplicate (same user): [How to get size of a dynamic allocated array of ints in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12196712/how-to-get-size-of-a-dynamic-allocated-array-of-ints-in-c)

Comment: @PaulR That is **not** the same question!!!

Comment: @Luchian: it has the exact same code with wild pointers in it and someone has already explained the problem in a comment. OP has ignored the comments and asked (part of) the same question again, hence it's a duplicate.

Comment: @PaulR, if the user uses the same code to ask _different things_, I believe it is by no means a duplicate _question_

Comment: @Singer: even if they have already had their problem diagnosed and have chosen to ignore it ?

Comment: @PaulR that question was wrongfuly edited (I reverted it back). Sorry, I didn't see that edit, but originally it did ask a completely different thing.

Comment: @Luchian: OK - I guess this is no longer a duplicate then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a pointer, that pointer has to point to something. So there are two steps: create the pointer, and create the thing it points to.

```
int *p, *q;    // create two pointers
int a;         // create something to point to
p = &a;        // make p point to a
*p = 0;        // set a to 0
q = new int;   // make q point to allocated memory
*q = 0;        // set allocated memory to 0
```

Comment: And you can also combine the two steps on one line as Luchian Grigore shows.

Comment: @Derek - yes, of course. I was illustrating the two steps, and combining them would muddle the lesson.

Comment: +1 for showing you can create a pointer to something on the stack (a), not just the heap (q).

Comment: @PeteBecker - I agree. I wasn't trying to criticize your answer. Just pointing it out.

Comment: I feel obligated to point out that any use of `new` should have a corresponding `delete` (or some way to release the memory).

Comment: @taz - Yes, certainly. This is a code snippet, intentionally incomplete.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know; not trying to be overly pedantic. I do things like that so in the future if someone is just learning C++ all the necessary information is together and they won't start writing code with memory leaks.

Answer (score 14):

```
WORKS:

int* p;
*p = 0;
```

**Nope!** It appears to work, but is in fact *undefined behavior*.

Declaring `int* whatever;` leaves you with an uninitialized pointer. You can't dereference it.

To initialize a pointer & set the value it points to to 0 (in your case):

```
int* p = new int(0);
```

Comment: So how to intialize it by 0? Without int x =0; int* p = &x;

Comment: He should probably be using a int value instead of an int pointer here...

Answer (score 2):

You didn't allocate any memory for your pointers, so you're getting Undefined behavior. Basically that means that *anything* could happen (including the possibility that it will work, too).

Use `int something = new int(<initialization_value>);` to initialize the pointer.