# Writing void fun(int *tab); and void fun(int tab[]) is the same?

Tags: c++, arrays

As in topics title. When I write: `void fun(int *tab){}` is it the same as writing `void fun(int tab[]){}` ?

Comment: If you don't count the extra character in `[]`...

Comment: @jrok: what do you mean? What 'extra character'?

Comment: `*` is one character, `[]` is two...

Comment: @StoryTeller: Oh, right

Comment: For readability if a function is expecting base address of an array, you can write the later one. If its just a pointer, you can write former one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
void fun(int *tab){}
void fun(int tab[]){}
void fun(int tab[10]){}  //whatever the size is
```

are all the same to the compiler. The array, with the size or not, decays to a pointer when passed as a function argument.

In practice, avoid using the last one, as it may give the implication that the size is known to the function, while actually it's not.

Comment: which makes it some of the most misleading syntactic sugar to a novice programmer...

Comment: @YuHao: just one more question before I accept your answer ;) Why would I ever write the last one, I mean: `void fun(int tab[10]){}` - whats the point of doing this? What exactly does it mean?

Comment: @nullpointer Arrays have a size, like `int arr[10];`, just when an array is passed as function argument, it's converted to a pointer to the first element, so the size is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, and no, the second version won't let you figure out the size of the array inside the function. It still decays to a pointer. :)

Comment: How could I figure out the size of the array with the first version?

Comment: @nullpointer, You can't. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` or something.

Comment: @nullpointer directly you can't. Use a `std::vector`, pass the size as a parameter, or mark the last element with a special value.

Comment: @nullpointer, you can't do that in the first version either. But some use the second in a misguided attempt to do so.

Comment: @jrok: I always do that. But it was interesting what Luchian Grigore wrote, I thought that there is another 'magic' way of doing this ;)

Comment: @nullpointer also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966964/what-does-this-c-code-mean

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is same..Whenever you declare an array say int tab[] in your program.. and if you want to pass that array to some other function then you actually pass the base address location of that array i.e. &tab[0], which is pointed by pointer that you use as argument in function, int *tab... This actually is call by reference..