# What does (void) sizeof (0[array]) mean?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I come across the following code, which returns the size of a C style array.

```
template <typename Type, int N>
int GetArraySize(Type (&array)[N])
{
    (void) sizeof (0[array]);
    return N;
}
```

The templated part seems to have been already explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966964/what-does-this-c-code-mean).

---

But still, I don't understand what is the utility of the `sizeof` line. Any ideas?
Some suggest that it is to avoid unused variable warning, but a simpler `#pragma`could have been used, right?

Moreover, will this piece of code be effective in any situation? Aren't there any restrictions?

Comment: `#pragma` is not standard (although most mainstream compilers do implement it), but casting to void is

Comment: `0[array]` is the same as `array[0]`

Comment: I see no point in sizeof line. `array` parameter name could be omitted to avoid unused variable warning. Also it should use and return `size_t`.

Comment: The compiler is not the only one that needs to understand the code.   A named parameter conveys information more clearly to a human reader, in this case that the it is intended than an array be passed.   And, once the parameter is named, there may be a wish to not trigger a compiler warning .....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the purpose of the line is to silent unused variable warning.
The simpler would be to omit parameter name

```
template <typename Type, int N>
int GetArraySize(Type (&)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Comment: Well, this warning could be silenced with `(void) array;` as well, why put sizeof with fancy indexing there?

Comment: Because why not? :D

Comment: @VTT -- who knows? People spend far too much time thinking of nutty ways to avoid warnings in legal, correct code.