# c++ pass array to function question

Tags: c++, arrays

How is it possible to pass an array parameter to a function, and calculate the size of the array parameter? Because every time i try to calculate it, the return value is always 4.

Thanks the fast replies. I'm going to pass the size of the array as well then. Or i give a shot to vectors. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is (one of) the difference between arrays and pointers. Taking the size of an array results in its size in bytes, whereas taking the size of a pointer yields the size of pointers on that system. **However**, whenever you pass an array to a function, it decays to a pointer, the size of which is always the same no matter what type of pointer it is (4 on a 32 bit machine).

So technically, it's impossible to pass an array into a function since whenever you try, it becomes a pointer.

You'll need to pass the size of the array in to the function as well, or better yet if you can, use `std::vector` or `std::array`, or `std::string` if you're using the array as a C-style string.

Comment: remember that `std::array` is only for c++1x

Answer (score 11):

You can do it using templates as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6106158):

```
template<size_t Size>
void AcceptsArray( ParameterType( &Array )[Size] )
{
    //use Size to find the number of elements
}
```

it is be called like this:

```
ParameterType array[100];
AcceptsArray( array ); //Size will be auto-deduced by compiler and become 100
```

The only drawback is that you now have a templated function and that increases code bloat. This can be addressed by redirecting the call to a non-templated function that accepts the address of the first element and the number of elements.

Comment: @saeed: That function accepts the array by reference. The size of array is auto-deduced at the point of instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ it is considered a bad pratice to use raw arrays. You should consider using `std::vector` or `boost::array` instead.

It is difficult to calculate the `size` of an array if you do not keep track of the size or supply some sort of an guardian value at the end. In C-strings (*not* `std::strings`), for example, the '\0' character marks the end of the string (a `char` array).

Answer (score 1):

This works with g++:

```
template <typename T>
std::size_t size_of_array (T const & array)
{
    return sizeof (array) / sizeof (*array);
}

int main ()
{
    int x [4];
    std::cout << "size: " << size_of_array (x) << '\n';
}
```

I guess it is because the function is inlined, but still it seems the array does not decay in this case. Can somebody explain why?

Comment: That indeed works on Visual C++ 10 even when inlining is off. I guess that would be a good separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c arrays it's not possible because they're automatically casted to pointer when passing it to a function. So 4 is the size of the pointer.

Solution: use `std::vector`

```
#include <vector>

int carray[] = {1,2,3,4};
std::vector<int> v(carray, carray + sizeof(carray)/sizeof(int));

my_function(v);
```

Comment: This doesn't work well for other types besides `int` because you make two copies of each item - one for the vector and one for the plain array. And the code was wrong when I downvoted but now it's corrected so I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: it's only an example... by the way, this is a faster way to write a ``std::vector`` initialization. Obviously it's not optimized, remember the question is about the result of the `sizeof`.