# Get length of static array

Tags: c++, arrays

Can someone explain to me why is this piece of code working (return size of a static array):

```
template<class T, size_t N>
size_t lenGood(const T (& arr) [N])
{
    return N;
}
```

And this piece don't (decays to pointer I guess):

```
template<class T, size_t N>
size_t lenBad(const T arr[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Sample main:

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 10,11,8,5,4,4 };

    auto sizeGood = lenGood(arr);
    //auto sizeBad = lenBad(arr); // won't compile: no instance of function matches for argument list

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Strongly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7177221/1207195

Comment: Though strongly related, this is probably more helpful: [How do I use arrays in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)